# Ajax elements dont see JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my php  page i append new buttons and information when press the button with JQuery Ajax,however when  i click the new button which came with ajax , its JQuery does not work but old button's JQuery works,i mean new button does not see the javascript file of my php page.

My JQuery Ajax Codes;

```
$("button[name='addnewelement']").click(function() {




$.ajax({    


    type: "POST",
    url: "addelement.php",

    cache: false,
    success: function(html){


    $("#new").append(html);// add new element into index.php
  });
  });
```

addelement.php;

```
  echo "
      .......
     <button id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="addnewelement"  >Add</button>
     ....... 
   " ;
```

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo` in the `addelement.php` page would be like

```
echo '<button id="'.$row['id'].'" name="addnewelement"  >Add</button>';
exit;
```

And also better to put the `exit` after the `echo`.Make sure that you follow the syntax and use a good IDE to find the syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **on click** event handler instead of **click** event handler.

Here is the link : http://api.jquery.com/on/

eg.

```
$( document).on( "click", "button[name='addnewelement']", function() {
$.ajax({    
    type: "POST",
    url: "addelement.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $("#new").append(html);// add new element into index.php
  });
});
```

Comment: The important thing is to use `.on()` with delegation, like you do in your answer. `.on()` without delegation is just the same as using `.click()` and won't work for dynamically added elements.

Comment: it does not add new element but it enters when clicking the button,why would not work ajax?

Comment: add `return false;` before closing on click function

Comment: i have already added it before,the problem is that,element which is created with ajax, cannot run ajax again.What am i missing?

Comment: Try adding click event on class instead of name. Name consider to be a unique value in HTML. I think that causing the problem.